# How do I write a cloud function that monitors a storage bucket?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have set up a Google Cloud Storage bucket to send notifications to a Pub/Sub topic:

`gsutil notification create -t my-topic -f json gs://test-bucket`

I have created a subscription to this topic to push messages to a cloud function endpoint:

`gcloud pubsub subscriptions create my-sub --topic my-topic`

And the cloud function is deployed with:

`gcloud functions deploy promo_received --region europe-west1 --runtime python37 --trigger-topic my-topic`

The purpose of the function (right now), is to check if a file being created in the test-bucket matches a specific file name, and to fire a message off to Slack when it does. Currently the function looks like this:

```
def promo_received(data):
    date_str = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    filename = json.loads(data)["name"]
    bucket = json.loads(data)["bucket"]

    if filename == 'PROM_DTLS_{}.txt.gz'.format(date_str):
        msg = ":heavy_check_mark: *{}* has been uploaded to *{}*. Awaiting instructions.".format(filename, bucket)
        post_to_slack(url, msg)
```

When I test this by dropping a file named `PROM_DTLS_20190913.txt.gz`, I can see the function fires, however it crashes with 2 errors:

`TypeError: promo_received() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not LocalProxy`

This is my first time attempting to do this, and I'm not sure where to start with troubleshooting. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `context` as argument for your function, that will solve the first error:

```
def promo_received(data, context):
    [...]
```

Also, you don't need `json.loads` to retrieve the name of the file or the bucket:

```
data['name']
data['bucket']
```

This should get rid of the second error.

Check the example in the [Google Cloud Storage Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage?hl=en-419#functions-calling-storage-python) documentation page

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have implemented the change as you suggested but now I am getting `KeyError: 'name'`.

Comment: @Cam I'm talking from memory here as I can't run test right now, but can you try with `data.get('name')` instead?

Answer (score 1):

To write a Python Cloud Function, look at [this example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#functions_calling_pubsub-python). Note that [Cloud Storage serializes the object into a utf-8 JSON string](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#payload), which Cloud Functions then base64-encodes. So you need to first base64-decode the payload, then utf8-decode it, then JSON parse it.

```
def promo_received(event, context):
  obj = json.loads(base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8'))
  filename = obj[“name”]
  bucket = obj[“bucket”]

  # the rest of your code goes here
```